# vboxdrv setup error in debian

Tags: virtualbox

I try to run this command in terminal and this error happened:

```
root@ali-lapdeb:/home/alireza# /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules ...failed!
  (Cannot unload module vboxdrv)
```

and this my dmesg output :

http://codepad.org/GjMsU9Rp

(I paste code here because i not allowed to enter this much code)

What is this lines :

```
[ 9557.201022]  [<ffffffffa0ea8000>] ? 0xffffffffa0ea7fff
[ 9557.201076]  [<ffffffffa0e69f77>] ? supdrvInitDevExt+0x187/0x780 [vboxdrv]
[ 9557.201144]  [<ffffffffa0e72e7e>] ? VBoxHost_RTMemAllocTag+0xe/0x30 [vboxdrv]
[ 9557.201202]  [<ffffffffa0ea8000>] ? 0xffffffffa0ea7fff
[ 9557.201255]  [<ffffffffa0ea8094>] ? VBoxDrvLinuxInit+0x94/0x1000 [vboxdrv]
[ 9557.201311]  [<ffffffff81002162>] ? do_one_initcall+0x112/0x170
[ 9557.201358]  [<ffffffff810c6937>] ? load_module+0x1b07/0x23f0
[ 9557.201403]  [<ffffffff810c3530>] ? m_show+0x1c0/0x1c0
[ 9557.201443]  [<ffffffff810c734d>] ? SyS_finit_module+0x6d/0x70
[ 9557.201491]  [<ffffffff814ae4f9>] ? system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
```

and what is my problem ?

---

linux debian testing,acer 5741G,

```
root@ali-lapdeb:/home/alireza# apt-cache policy virtualbox
virtualbox:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.3.10-dfsg-1
  Version table:
     4.3.10-dfsg-1 0
        500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ testing/contrib amd64 Packages
     4.3.6-dfsg-2 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
root@ali-lapdeb:/home/alireza# uname -a
Linux ali-lapdeb 3.13-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.13.7-1 (2014-03-25) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```